# Android TV - Is it possible to run a background app to receive notifications?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have searched this forum for similar questions and dont see any question related to mine in the past couple of years so want to ask if the latest version of Android TV can receive notifications in the background?

We currently have Android/iOS apps that can receive messages from our messaging server that users subscribe to. This all works great, but was wondering if I could write something similar, an Android TV app that can run in the background while a user is watching something like Netflix/Amazon etc.. (It would show the message on top of the current app).

A simple popup on the TV over the app that they are currently using (like Netflix) with the function to ignore/click to read more.

Is this possible?

TIA.